# resizing rectangle within triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Imagine I have a parking lot that changes in width and length and in number of levels, and all of the levels need to be visible to a cctv camera at a fixed position, and I would want the camera to see as much as possible so the boundaries of the parking lot need to match the boundaries of the field of view of the camera. the parking lot can be moved backwards forwards and up and down, and the height of the levels can be increased or decreased.

So in short,

**variables I don't control:** number of levels, level width,level length.

**things that I can change:** position of the parking lot, height of the levels.

**constants:** angle and position of camera

I have attached a diagram at the end, where $z = 30$, $w = 20$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the points of the parking lot I need to align to the triangle.

The height of the triangle is known and can increase if needed.

$x$ and $y$ are known as are **rWidth** and **rHeight**.

> **gHeight**, **yTrans**, and **zTrans** are what I need to derive.

What I'm looking for is an equation I can put in my constant values of $w$ and $z$, put in my changing values of rectangle width and number of levels, and come out with values for **gHeight**, **yTrans**, and **zTrans** so it makes everything fit and visible. Or even just general direction as to what I should be using to solve it, simultaneous equations for example.

I am able to calculate $C_3$ position whilst keeping **gHeight** static using the method below. Now I'm just trying to find out how to do this whilst playing with **gHeight** to keep the levels visible.

\begin{align*}
\text{Total_Length} &= \textbf{rHeight} \cdot \sin W \cdot \tan(180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}-0.5\, Z) \\
&\hspace{2pt} + \textbf{rHeight} \cdot \cos W + \cos 45^{\circ} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth} \\
&\hspace{2pt} + \tan(180^{\circ} - 90 ^{\circ} - 0.5\, Z) \cdot \sin 45^{\circ} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth} +\cos 45^{\circ} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth}
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\textbf{z position of}~C_3 &= \cos(0.5\, Z) \cdot  0.5 \cdot \textbf{Total_Length} \\
\textbf{y position of}~C_3 &= \cos 45^{\circ} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth} + \tan(180^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} - 0.5\, Z) \cdot \sin 45^{\circ} \\
&\hspace{36pt} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth} + \cos 45^{\circ} - w \cdot \textbf{rWidth}
\end{align*}

[image]